# Selecting pull down item with python selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to select an item from a pull down list. I've been searching and trying everything.  I've tried to search and select by id, xpath, and name.  I am at a complete loss.  I keep seeing select_by_value but I get the error 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_value'

The code from the website that I'm trying to select from is as follows.

```
<input type="hidden" name="wlw-select_key:{actionForm.dobMonth}OldValue" value="true">
<select name="wlw-select_key:{actionForm.dobMonth}" id="dobMonth" class="dobMonth">   <option value="">Select month</option>
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option></select>
```

I've tried both working with the numerical value and the text value, but neither have worked.  I've also tried selecting with the id and then sending keyboard commands.  The best that I can get it to do is to open the menu, but it does not change the value.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('dobMonthSelectBoxItContainer').send_keys("May")
```

doesn't give errors, but when I find by xpath or name I do get errors.  I've been using firepath to get the xpath, which would be

```
.//*[@id='genderSelectBoxItText']
```

and

```
.//*[@id='5']/a
```

(I've gotten to the 5th page on several google searches :/ Most I see using the select command, but I keep getting that error.)

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use the `Select()` class when handling a `<select>` element.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("dobMonth"))
select.select_by_visible_text("May")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that code results in this output http://pastebin.com/tyBn4ehx I've seen that on google, and it's failed me :( I frequently see that error about it not being visible, if that helps with the solution.

Comment: @StevenWalton if the element isn't visible, you'll usually need for it to wait for the element before you can interact with it. `wait.until(ExceptedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "yourId"))`

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, but it is bulky and seems to take more time than necessary. The solution I have created is the following code.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('dobMonthSelectBoxItText').click()
time.sleep(1) #requires "import time"
driver.find_element_by_id('dobMonthSelectBoxItText').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('5').click()
```

This seems to open the box twice, but if I remove any line it does not work. I feel that this is bad coding technique, but this is a working solution. I would still appreciate a more elegant solution than this, if anyone finds one.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle dropdowns  with Selenium

```
def select_dropdown(driver, dropdown_id, option_value):
    dd = driver.find_element_by_id(dropdown_id)
    xpath = ".//option[@value='{}']".format(option_value)
    dd.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

In your case, if you were trying to select May, as in your example code, it would be `select_dropdown(driver, 'dobMonth','05')`.